# Building OSX Npapi plugin on xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, npapi

I have built a sample npapi plugin (.msi) which works on windows platform for firefox. Now i have been trying to build the same code for xcode(4.6.3) on mac os X. Which template are we supposed to use for creating a new project for npapi in xcode on mac? (eg application plugin,system plugin,framework & library :has subcategories too)

Although I could successfully compile the same code in xcode using Application Plug-in (with subcategory installer plug-in) and it generates a .bundle but i don't know what to do with it?
Also i read that we need to create .plugin for mac plugin and keep it at /Library/Internet Plug-Ins. if that is the case then how do we create a .plugin file extension by building my code?

Comment: In case you aren't aware, NPAPI support is being removed from Chrome shortly, and Mozilla describes it as a legacy technology, so building a new NPAPI plugin at this point is probably a bad idea for almost any use case.

Comment: If not NPAPI then what should i use as an alternate to NPAPI so that plugin would be supported on all browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568920/alternatives-to-npapi-plugins/21569141#21569141 (Also, NPAPI is not supported on all browsers, IE being another notable exception; the only thing that likely to work in all browsers in the web platform itself.)

Answer (score 1):

For an example of an Xcode project that generates an NPAPI plugin, see the Mac example project in https://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/ (which you should already be using for your headers, since it's the canonical source).