# How to develop web browser plugins instead of NPAPI(Deprecated from most of browsers)?

Tags: javascript, plugins, rtsp, npapi

I want to **develop a browser plugin** for RTSP streaming on web browser, I read about NPAPI, which can execute native code(C++). But Google Chrome will not support NPAPI in future and no guaranty about Firefox also.

Please somebody can suggest me to "**How can I develop plugin which can execute native code(OR any other language) using other framework instead of NPAPI?**".

How can I add RTSP Streaming support for web browsers?

Comment: native client might be able to do that level of custom networking; if not, your only option for Chrome at least would be to use Native Messaging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to NPAPI plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568920/alternatives-to-npapi-plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot implement universal plugin at the moment. It's possible to write extensions for Chrome and Firefox which support TCP and UDP sockets ([Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network#tcp), [Mozilla API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) ). No such thing for Microsoft Edge or Explorer or Safari as far as I know.

If using different streaming protocol is an option, consider [WebRTC](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/). Its support is [still not very good](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/), but at least WebRTC is an official standard and has better chances of being adopted.

Comment: Thanks smirnoff. I want to broadcast stream in multiple client using WebRTC, So I am planing to Use Node.js for Server implementation. All clients will be connect to that server. So have you any exact solution(reference, open source project) to do this?

Comment: I know several resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552333/is-it-possible-to-use-webrtc-to-streaming-video-from-server-to-client, and https://github.com/muaz-khan?tab=repositories. Last one has tons of examples for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to develop an extension for the major browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari) then I'd suggest looking into the kango framework. It takes a common code base and converts it into plugins for 3 of the 4 major browsers (for IE you'll have to contact them)

Comment: Kango framework is best framework to replace NPAPI. But my problem is that I want to user RTSP streaming, So I need to create TCP socket for RTSP communication for vodeo streming. I am searching solution for TCP socket communication, So I need plugin with any programming language which support TCP socket. Kango framework  support purly Javascript and TCP socket are not supported in Javascript.